# Should we try to add backlinks using a blog or paid backlink services?

Tags: seo, blog, backlinks

I'm new to SEO, I've just started my business last month and I want to get backlinks, but I don't know where I can start. Should I create a new blog (like Blogger or Tumblr), or use backlink services?

If I shouldn't , can you tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make outstanding content that people will want to link to.

Second, make sure your site performs as well as it can in the search engines.

Third, give your site some time to settle into the search engines as you create new content at least weekly.

Fourth, ask for back links from quality sites on a page by page basis where the linking page topic compliments your target pages topic. This takes real work and will not be easy or fast. However, these links are the most valuable. Make sure these are quality sites with real rank, trust, and authority. You may not get the big boys to like to your site, but you can still get good sites to link to your site.

Fifth, engage in social media heavily and promote your content. If you are posting on your site, then you will be sending a twitter message every time you post. Create a form that exists on each page that allows a user to sign-up for e-mail updates. Send an e-mail between every week and every month depending upon how much content you create. Create social sharing buttons for your site. This does not provide a lot of movement, but enough to make a real difference. Facebook can be good for some sites, but not all. It depends on the topic and how involved with people you want to be. Facebook represents additional work as much, if not more, than having a website. This is something to think about.

Sixth, if you can be a guest blogger/writer for another site with a byline that is linked to your site, then do that as much as possible. If the byline is not linked, then it is something to think about. Citations still count, especially bylines as these are recognized by search engines.

Do not create a blog that is not on your site. You will be creating value for someone else and not for your site.

Do not use forums, comment sections, blogs, for cheap links. These are often `nofollow` links which still have value, but these sites generally do not much value. Some do, however, search engines have begun to downgrade these activities.

Do not create entries on directories with some exception. Very few have any trust and rank to share. What does exist is shared amongst all of the links on the page. DMOZ is one directory that still ranks well with high trust, however, it has lost real value lately and is hard to get a link from sometimes. It is too iffy. There are some fairly well managed niche directories. You can look for a list of directories that rates them. Look for rank and trust values, otherwise the list of directories has no value and should be ignored.

`DO NOT USE(!)` link services, buy links, rent links, use link exchange programs or anything like them.

These are some of the general guidelines that exist today.

The most valuable thing you can do is create as much content as you can that people want to link to. Let them discover it themselves and pass your content to their circle of friends however they do it. Any link made organically is always the best. You cannot control who links to your site, however, if it is an honest link whether the linking site has value or not, it should help you anyway. Search engines prefer this most of all.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I will start working like a bee now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a budget, then write interesting content and promote the content via social media adverts to people who may be interested.  Paid advertising saves a lot of time having to build your own audience to advertise to, though gaining your own audience is not a bad long-term aim.

Ultimately, Google want to see natural links, so your job is to let the people who may link know that your page exists.

Never use a backlinks service.  Google Penguin hit these hard - half of them have now become "link removal" services!